# Щадящее сканирование NMAP

Tags: сканирование-портов, сканирование

Существует ли способ сканирования для NMAP слабых устроств или медленных сетей так, чтобы сканирование их грузило минимально? Иными словами, существует ли способ сканирования с минимальной нагрузкой на сеть, пусть и не быстрый? Первое, что пришло в голову — это --mtu, но, возможно, есть другой способ

Comment: вот тут описано множество опций, отвечающих за интенсивность сканирования https://nmap.org/man/ru/man-performance.html. Также стоит для начала определиться с целями, т.к. разные цели (например, ping и полный скан портов) порождают разную нагрузку.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Для моих целей отлично подходит --max-rate